# Cannot use Redis cache in Dotnet Core 3.0

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

according to the [Distributed caching in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed?view=aspnetcore-3.0#distributed-redis-cache)

It is said I can using `Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.StackExchangeRedis` and using `services.AddStackExchangeRedisCache` in `ConfigureServices`

However the namespace `Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.StackExchangeRedis` not exists on dotnet core 3.0.

there is only `using Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory;` and `using Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Distributed;` exists

Comment: Did you install the StackExchangeRedis nuget package? https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.StackExchangeRedis

Comment: @Phill, thanks, indeed, I not install this package, but the official doc is not written about install this package

Answer (score 10, accepted):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed?view=aspnetcore-3.0#prerequisites

The `Prerequisits` section higher up in the linked document state you need to add a reference to the package `Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.StackExchangeRedis`